# Probability of sum of two randomly picked numbers from a specific range

Tags: probability, probability-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

What is the probability that the sum of two randomly picked numbers from the range 1-100 (inclusive) is divisible by 5?

My approach:

For the 1st number, the probability is $$\frac{1}{100}.$$ For the 2nd number, the set is decreased by one (the 1st number we choosed) so possible outcomes are 99. For the favourable outcomes part, we look for numbers that complement the 1st selected number so their sum (module 5) = 0. Since there are 20 numbers that are divisible by 5 in the mentioned range, probability is $$\frac{20}{99}.$$ Combining gives $$\frac{20}{100\times99}.$$

Is my answer correct?

Comment: Why is the probability $1/100$ for the first one? (What does this represent, exactly?)

Comment: I don't think so, whatever the first number is, the second number has a 1 in 5 chance of making the sum divisible by 5

Comment: I am assuming that you can use the same number twice

Comment: Something to think about--in general for probability problems--based on the first comment, "Why a probability of $1/100$ for the first one?" The first number is randomly picked from $[1,100]$... but you can be absolutely certain that *a number was picked*. The probability of randomly picking $42$ is $1/100$, but the probability of picking "a number" is 100%. The first "choice" having 100% probability is common in these problems.

Comment: I have removed the **divisor-sum** tag, since this problem has nothing to do with the $\sigma$-function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually. it is as follows:

Lets consider instead the remainder modulo 5 of the numbers 1 to 100, so we have 20 1's, 20 2's .. 20 4's and 20 0's.

The combination of numbers whose sum is divisible by 5 are

1 4, probability of 1 then a 4 is $\frac{20}{100} \times \frac{20}{99} $

2 3, probability of 2 then a 3 is $\frac{20}{100} \times \frac{20}{99} $

3 2, probability of 3 then a 2 is $\frac{20}{100} \times \frac{20}{99} $

4 1, probability of 4 then a 1 is $\frac{20}{100} \times \frac{20}{99} $

0 0, probability of 0 then a 0 is $\frac{20}{100} \times \frac{19}{99} $

So you have $$4 \times \left(\frac{20}{100} \times \frac{20}{99}\right) + \frac{20}{100} \times \frac{19}{99} $$

which is $$\frac{1980}{9900} = 0.2 $$

Comment: If you allow repetition it is just 5*(20/100)^2 = 1/5 = 0.2